# How to deny access to port 80 of the server to everyone except ip 192.168.0.36?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

How to deny access to port 80 of the server to everyone except ip 192.168.0.36?

What I do wrong:

> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp —dport 80 ! -s 192.168.0.36 -j DROP

Bad argument `—dport` =(

Comment: Which distro? Ubuntu comes with [`ufw`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) by default, which is easier to manage. `ufw allow from 192.168.0.36 to any port 80`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try like this:-

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 192.168.0.36 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```